# Duplicating an ActiveRecord in Rails, issues creating new object using existing paramters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to duplicate a resource in Rails in my application and was running into some issues.

The setup is: I have a library of 'item templates' that the user can use, then modify the resulting item. I currently have a setup like this:

```
@temp_item = @template_item.dup
@new_item = @user.items.create(@temp_item.attributes)
```

However I'm running into a problem where it's trying to copy across protected attributes as well (namely created_at and updated_at). I'd rather not list out each attribute individually, so my question is, **is there a way to exclude attributes being copied in this instance?**

Thanks.

Comment: Besides `created_at` and `updated_at`, you probably also have to exclude `id`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Incorporating Mischa's good suggestion into my original answer.

```
@temp_item_attributes = @template_item.attributes.reject{ |k,v|
  %w(created_at updated_at).include?(k)
}
@new_item = @user.items.create(@temp_item_attributes)
```

Comment: Edited to incorporate Mischa's suggestion.

Comment: this doesn't work if I don't include "id" in the rejected attributes list. `%w(created_at updated_at id).include?(k)`

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Mark in using [`reject`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Array/reject), but instead of using `case`/`when`, I'd do this:

```
@template_item.attributes.reject{ |k,v| %w(created_at updated_at).include?(k) }
```

Answer (score 2):

seems to me you should do a combination of Mark Paine and Mischa's answers, namely:

```
temp_item_attributes = @template_item.attributes.reject do |k,v|
  %w(created_at updated_at).include?(k)
end
@new_item = @user.items.create(temp_item_attributes)
```

I can't believe there isn't a convenience method for this behavior; I didn't look too hard, but didn't find one.

Comment: I was only showing the `reject` part because the rest is obvious, but thanks for expanding.